# How to prevent Fingerprinting via Font Enumeration

Tags: privacy, javascript, flash

I don't mean using Noscript or just not installing fonts, I'm trying to find a way of outright denying Flash, Java, and JavaScript the ability to look at my fonts. I've checked the fonts folder and it didn't have a property tab so I couldn't go into the security tab and change the settings there.

Is there a way to prevent device fingerprinting via font enumeration?

Comment: I seem to remember a proposal for a script that would randomly change the order of reported fonts

Answer (score 3):

If your on Mac or Linux there is a little program on Github called [FluxFonts](https://github.com/Aeyoun/fluxfonts) which may do what you need. According to the Read Me file:

> Fluxfonts – a continual font generator for increased privacy
>   ...
>   New fonts are generated by the daemon every 2 to 40 minutes. Fonts are generated at random times in this time window. However, they are generated more often when not running on battery power.

I've actually never tried it, but if it works as stated then this should be a great way to avoid font fingerprinting in your browser.

Comment: Author of Fluxfonts here. It doesn’t prevent fingerprinting. It just makes sure your fingerprint changes several times per hour. Making your font fingerprint useless as a source of a recreatable fingerprint. There is no other software like Fluxfonts and there is no Windows version (yet!).